# Skype doesn't show video fine on Acer Aspire S5 (ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: 16.04, video, skype

I have a strange behavior during skype calls. When the other party doesn't send video, the video from my webcam looks ok. When I don't send my video, I see other's video semi-ok (in a small box inside the screen, without the flickering of the blue background).

[image: how it looks on the laptop]

Ubuntu 16.04 64bit
Acer Aspire S5 (on Core i3 i6100)
skype 4.3

In the pro

lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b580 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04ca:3016 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d18 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

Answer (score 0):

It helped me to use `20-intel.conf` from this repository & updating firmware:

https://github.com/linuxenko/ubuntu-skylake-i915-video-fix

Installing kernel 4.6 alone didn't help, I rolled back to 4.4.